# Amber Smalltalk and XMLHttpRequest (GET)

Tags: xmlhttprequest, http-get, amber-smalltalk

I try to print

```
| req |
req := XMLHttpRequest new.
req open: 'GET' url: 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/' asynchronous: false.
req send: ''.
req responseText
```

The debugger tells me

```
[Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location:
"JS frame ::   http://amber-lang.net/amber/js/boot.js :: callJavaScriptMethod ::
 line 651" data: no]
```

This happens in a workspace on the current amber IDE on http://amber-lang.net/

**Notes:**

I have translated the JavaScript message

```
req.open("GET", url, false);
```

according to the message conversion rules noted at http://amber-lang.net/documentation.html#JSObjectProxy

**Update after answer by SLaks**

The following code snippet

```
| req |
req := XMLHttpRequest new.
req open: 'GET' url: 'http://amber-lang.net/' asynchronous: false.
req send: ''.
req responseText
```

works indeed when executing it in the IDE opened from http://amber-lang.net.

The answer is

```
'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Amber Smalltalk</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Nicolas Petton" />

 ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, you cannot use AJAX to read from another domain.
(unless it explicitly allows you)

This is called the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).